# Scale up a string to another string with higher length

Tags: c++

I need to scale up a string like "110021" that has a length of 6 to a string with length of for example 12

So probably method should return something like: "111100002211"

Comment: On what basis should the scaling happen ? There are quite a good member functions of std::string to modify the string.

Comment: Think about how many times you need to repeat every character, and you're home :)

Comment: On what basis? I say you scale up the string! The string with length 300 scale it to a string with length 1230!

Comment: @EBAG: but you haven't really described the scaling. You say that one specific string should **probably** be transformed into **something like** another string. If you can't describe the algorithm you want to use, then no one can tell you how to implement it. Would it be valid to scale `"110021"`  up to `110021      "?

Comment: @EBAG: how "01" should be scaled to a string of length 3?

Comment: Is this homework? Also, am I right to assume that you want each digit in the first string to be repeated?

Comment: @jbungalobill : I'm not sure, probaby '001'

Comment: In this example, it looks like the length of the new string has to be a multiple (n) of the original length and every character of the original string has to be repeated n times in the new string.

Comment: @EBAG, you need to be a bit more detailed. If you don't know the problem yourself how can we know whats going on ?

Comment: @EBAG, You can either edit this question or post a new one.  Since this has answers, there's no reason to delete it.  It might be useful to other in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string original = "110021";
std::string result;
size_t new_length = 12;

// need (multiple) copies of each char, plus an extra one of each of the first
// (remainder) chars
size_t multiple = new_length / original.size();
size_t remainder = new_length % original.size();

// not strictly necessary, but since we already know the result's length...
result.reserve(new_length);

for (char c : original) {
    result.append(multiple, c);
    if (remainder) { result.append(1, c); --remainder; }
}
```

For that last part, if you don't have decent C++11 support yet:

```
for (std::string::iterator it = original.begin(); it != original.end(); ++it) {
    result.append(multiple, *it);
    if (remainder) { result.append(1, *it); --remainder; }
}
```

Note, this semi breaks when the new length is less than the old one.  (It will add the first new_length chars to the string, and then stop.)  If you want certain behavior, you should probably specify things more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that is almost correct. I deliberately introduced a small bug, so that I don't do your homework completely. Advanced C or C++ programmers will spot the bug immediately, because it already smells like a bug.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::size_t;
using std::string;

/** a * b / c, rounded towards zero. */
size_t muldiv(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c) {
  unsigned long long product = a * b;
  assert(a == 0 || product / a == b);
  return product / c;
}

string scale(const string &s, size_t new_length) {
  string result;

  for (size_t i = 0; i <= new_length; i++) {
    size_t index = muldiv(i, s.length(), new_length);
    result += s.at(index);
  }
  return result;
}

void assert_equals(const string &expected, const string &actual) {
  if (expected != actual) {
    std::cerr << "Expected \"" << expected << "\", got \"" << actual << "\".\n";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

void test_scale() {
  assert_equals("111100002211", scale("110021", 12));
  assert_equals("110021", scale("110021", 6));
  assert_equals("102", scale("110021", 3));
  assert_equals("1111222333444", scale("1234", 13));
}

int main() {
  try {
    test_scale();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::string x("110022");
    std::string y;
    unsigned int newLenght = 40;  // for example

    for (std::string::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newLenght / x.length(); i++)
        {
            y += *it;
        }
    }
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This just doubles the length! I say any length to any length transformation!

Comment: And how do we repeat characters? as many times up to new lenght?

Comment: For your example, given newLenght (ugh) of 40, you'll still end up with only 36 chars in your string.